# Reset the date portion to the last of the month while preserving the time

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to reset the date portion to the last day of the month while preserving the time? For example:

```
2018-01-02 23:00:00 -> 2018-01-31 23:00:00
2018-04-04 10:00:00 -> 2018-04-30 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle function [`last_day()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm) does exactly this.  Try:

```
select last_day(sysdate), sysdate
from dual
```

to see how it works.

Ironically, I usually find the preservation of the date to be counterintuitive, so my usual usage is more like:

```
select last_day(trunc(sysdate))
from dual
```